# How can we call internal API endpoints within the app in golang (gorilla/mux)?

Tags: rest, go, gorilla, mux

I am Using: http://github.com/gorilla/mux (REST API)

*basically need to achieve this, but in golang*
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/345406/is-it-bad-design-to-internally-call-api-endpoints-from-within-the-api-instance

*I tried finding it in the docs but wasn't able to

I presume, it is better to do these calls internally!*

**Reasons for doing this:**

1. Using existing handler or services would need unnecessary imports & may lead to import cycle errors.
2. I want to create cronjobs which will periodically call my API endpoints

Comment: In theory you can do this by creating an HTTP server but you should be calling the handler behind that api endpoint. HTTP endpoints are just that, they should be called over http. if you have import errors, you fix them. You can create a separate package to help with that, but its not a good reason for what you are trying to achieve